# After upgrade from Fedora 23 to 25, ps2 keyboard is not recogized

Tags: fedora, keyboard

I can't seem to get fedora 25 to recognize my ps2 model m keyboard. It is not recognized by the bios but that never mattered before. I'm running kernel 4.10, it does appear to be recognized in 4.8 though. Upgrade was done via the dnf system upgrade plugin.

Comment: I suggest you [file a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/) since this is obviously a regression. The input maintainers are very responsive but they don’t read U&L!

Comment: @StephenKitt What component should I submit it as?

Comment: Pick “kernel”, since that appears to be the source of the issue (as evidenced by the fact that 4.8 works while 4.10 doesn’t).